# Как учитывать интервал в командной строке?

Tags: java, windows

Привет всем. Делаю приложение на Java, которое отключает монитор на Windows. 
Есть такая команда

```
Runtime.getRuntime().exec(new String[]{"scrnsave.scr","/s","start"});}
```

Но необходимо, чтобы эта команда сработала через X-интервал. Допустим, 3 секунды. 
Каким образом это реализовать? Какой есть параметр? Не могу найти

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Добавьте задержку

```
try {
    // время в мс, в данном случае 3 сек
    Thread.sleep(3000);
} catch(InterruptedException ex) {
    // на первых порах можно его просто игнорировать
}

Runtime.getRuntime().exec(new String[]{"scrnsave.scr","/s","start"});}
```

Comment: Спасибо. Вроде работает!

Comment: Лучше через ScheduledExecutorsPool